# "Cannot convert type" from Class in WebServiceSoapClient to same Class in Client app

Tags: asp.net, web-services, type-conversion

I have a Web Service with a WebMethod thus:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<CalendarRecord> GetCalendar()
{
    list = new List<CalendarRecord>();
    list.Add(new CalendarRecord
    { 
        ID = "1", 
        Name = "2015" 
    });

    return list;
}
```

And in my client c# app, I am consuming this WebMethod thus:

```
MyWebService.MyWebServiceSoapClient service = new MyWebService.MyWebServiceSoapClient();
CalendarRecord[] soapResults = service.GetCalendar();
```

Both the WebService and the client app have references to the same Model Classes / DLL, which provide the definition for the "CalendarRecord" class.

However, this won't compile - I get the message:

```
Error:
    Cannot implicitly convert type 'ThisApp.MyWebService.CalendarRecord[]' to 'Model.CalendarRecord[]'
```

So - how do I get the client app to recognise that the type being returned from the WebService is the exact same class as the one being used locally?

The 'CalendarRecord' class is simply defined thus:

```
using System;

namespace Model
{
    public class CalendarRecord
    {
        private string _id;
        private string _name;

        public String ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Both the WebService and the Client App have the project that contains the CalendarRecord definition included and in the References.  They also have the following in each relevant class:

```
using Model;
```

Intellisense shows that the correct Model.CalendarRecord class is being referred to in the code in each.  Yet the compiler still objects!

=====================================================

This gets weirder... I have several of these Type Conversion errors occurring for different calls to the WebService, but NOT ALL of them exhibit the problem.  I now have two base classes, 'Model.CalendarRecord' and 'Model.WeekRecord' which are absolutely identical, except for their names.  The Web Service then has two methods which it is exposing, 'GetCalendar()' and 'GetWeek()', which apart from referencing the relevant underlying models are also functionally identical.

BUT, in my client App - 
CalendarRecord[] soapResults = service.GetCalendar(); 
...causes the type conversion error, whereas - 
WeekRecord[] soapResults = service.GetWeek()
...compiles without problem.

Intellisense shows the first one to be of type:

'ThisApp.MyWebService.CalendarRecord[]

...and the second one to be of type:

'Model.WeekRecord[]'

So why is the WebService exposing these differently, when all the underlying code is identical, except for the names???

Comment: Can you post definition of CalendarRecord class? Also have you defined CalendarRecord in client application? Looks like there is definition of 'CalendarRecord class exists locally in client application.

Comment: I have added some more details...

Comment: Try changing this line CalendarRecord[] soapResults = service.GetCalendar(); to MyWebService.CalendarRecord[] soapResults = service.GetCalendar();

Comment: Thanks Pankaj.
That works, in that it stops the immediate Type Conversion Error, but all it does is pass the problem onto the next piece of code.  As soon as I try to do anything with the 'soapResults' array, I get another type error -  I need to be able to manipulate that as an array of Model.CalendarRecord objects and they are now MyWebService.CalendarRecord objects!

Comment: I fond out something weirder about this, and have included a description at the end of my original post

Comment: You should be able to serialize your object and deserialize as the correct class.